# Al subir un proyecto no visualiza las imágenes correctamente

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, xmlhttprequest

Acabo de subir un proyecto a infinityfree, intento de red social.

Pude crear la base de datos y conectarla, pero en la mayoría de las cosas el ajax no funciona.

Funciona solo en un caso:

[image: Captura de pantalla de algo que parece que funciona]

Pero en el resto del proyecto no funciona nada.

La idea es cargar publicaciones por ajax con sus correspondientes funciones.

Así debería ser:

[image: Captura de pantalla de cómo debería verse la web]

Como se ve realmente:

[image: Captura de pantalla de cómo se ve en la actualidad]

La consola me tira el siguiente error:

> Cross-Origin Read Blocking (CORB) blocked cross-origin response https://infinityfree.net/errors/404/ with MIME type text/html. See https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5629709824032768 for more details.

¿Será por que no especifico el `content-type` en el ajax?

Leí un artículo que marca que a veces se dan cruces en los accesos a recursos e implementando estas cabeceras se soluciona:

```
<?php
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, PUT, DELETE');
```

Pero no logro hacerlo andar.

¿Algún consejo? ¿Qué debería leer?

Codigo que funciona

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    const buscar = $("#buscador");
    const elementoDiv = $("#espacioBuscador");
    const elementoPerfiles = $("#divBuscador")[0];
    let perfiles = "";
    function modeloPerfil(objeto){
        perfiles +=`<a href="perfil.php?usuario=${objeto.usuario_perfil}" class="perfilPublicacion" style="text-decoration:none;"><div class="imgPerfilListaHistorias"><img src="imagenes/perfiles/${objeto.cuenta_id}/${objeto.image}" alt="${objeto.usuario_perfil}"></div><div class="infoPerfilListaHistorias"><p class="usuario">${objeto.usuario_perfil}</p><p class="nombre">${objeto.nombre_perfil}</p></div></a>`
    }
    const buscando = () => {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            elementoDiv[0].style.display = "flex";
            resolve();
        });
    }
    buscar.click(function(){
       buscando()
       .then(function(){
           login = $(".navegacion > a:nth-child(3) > img:nth-child(1)")[0].attributes.alt.value;
           $.ajax({
            data: {
                buscarPerfiles:"buscar"
            },
            url: "funciones/modelo-buscar.php",
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(r){
                // console.log(r,login);
                for(let i = 0; i < r.length; i++){
                    if(r[i].usuario_perfil != login){
                        modeloPerfil(r[i]);
                    }
                }
                elementoPerfiles.innerHTML = perfiles;
            }
           })
           .then(function(){
                buscar[0].oninput = function(){
                //    console.log(this.value);
                   caracteres = (this.value).toLowerCase();
                   buscarEn = $("#divBuscador")[0].childNodes;
                   for(let i = 0; i < buscarEn.length; i++){
                       let usuario = buscarEn[i].childNodes[1].childNodes[0].textContent.toLowerCase();
                       let nombre = buscarEn[i].childNodes[1].childNodes[1].textContent.toLowerCase();
                       if(usuario.indexOf(caracteres) != -1 || nombre.indexOf(caracteres) != -1){
                           buscarEn[i].style.display = "flex";
                       }else{
                           buscarEn[i].style.display = "none";
                       }
                   }
               }
           })
       })
       .then(function(){
            body = $("body");
            elementoDiv[0].addEventListener("click",(e)=>{
                // console.log(e.target.attributes[0].value);
                if(e.target.attributes[0].value == "espacioBuscador"){
                    elementoDiv[0].style.display = "none";
                    perfiles = "";
                    buscar[0].value = "";
                }
            });
       })
    });
})
```

Por ejemplo esto no funciona:

```
 //Insertar publicaciones
    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    $.ajax({
        method: "POST",
        url: "funciones/modelo-publicacion.php",
        data: {
                perfil: "cargarPublicacionesIndex",
                id: idActual
            },
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(r){
        //    console.log(r);
           var arraySeguidos = [];
           for(let i = 0; i < r.UsuariosSeguidos.length; i++){
               arraySeguidos.push(r.UsuariosSeguidos[i].usuario_seguido);
           }
        //    console.log(arraySeguidos);
           for(let i = 0; i < r.Publicaciones.length; i++){
               if(r.Publicaciones[i].id_perfil == idActual || arraySeguidos.indexOf(r.Publicaciones[i].id_perfil) >= 0){
                   arrayComentarios = [];
                   for(let o = 0; o < r.comentarios.length; o++){
                       if(r.comentarios[o].publicacion_id == r.Publicaciones[i].id_publicacion){
                           arrayComentarios.push(r.comentarios[o]);
                       }
                   }
                   arrayMG = [];
                   for(let a = 0; a < r.megustas.length; a++){
                       if(r.megustas[a].publicacion_id == r.Publicaciones[i].id_publicacion){
                           arrayMG.push(r.megustas[a]);
                       }
                   }
                   mostrarPublicaciones(r.Publicaciones[i],arrayComentarios,arrayMG);
               }     
           }
           listaPublicaciones.innerHTML = divPublicaciones;
        }
    })
    .then(function(){
        const btnComentar = $(".interaccionPublicacion .botonesInteraccion button:nth-child(2)");
        for(let i = 0; i < btnComentar.length; i++){
            btnComentar[i].addEventListener("click",(e)=>{
                textarea = e.target.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.childNodes[11].childNodes[1].childNodes[1];
                textarea.focus();
            })
        }
        // console.log(o);
        // Boton heart
        //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        const btnHeart = $(".interaccionPublicacion .botonesInteraccion button:nth-child(1)");
        for(let i = 0; i < btnHeart.length; i++){
            btnHeart[i].addEventListener("click",(e)=>{
                    // console.log(e.target.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.childNodes[3].childNodes[1].childNodes[1].innerText);
                    // span
                    span = e.target.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.childNodes[3].childNodes[1].childNodes[1];
                    boton = e.target.parentNode;
                    idPub = e.target.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.childNodes[1].textContent;
                    ajaxMG(idPub,idActual,boton,span);  
            })
        }

        // Insertar comentario
        //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

        //Desactivar boton con texarea sin value
        const botonComentar = $(".comentar button");
        const textComentar = $(".comentar textarea");
        for(let i = 0; i < botonComentar.length; i++){
            botonComentar[i].disabled = true;
            textComentar[i].oninput = function(){
                if(textComentar[i].value == ""){
                    botonComentar[i].disabled = true;
                }else{
                    botonComentar[i].disabled = false;
                }
            }; 
        }

        const formComentar = $(".comentar");
        for(let i = 0; i < formComentar.length; i++){
            formComentar[i].addEventListener("submit",(e)=>{
                e.preventDefault();
                idPub = e.target.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.childNodes[1].innerText;
                txt = e.target.childNodes[1].value;
                cantMsjs = e.target.parentNode.parentNode.childNodes[5].childNodes[1].childNodes[1].innerText;
                cajonMsjs = e.target.parentNode.parentNode.childNodes[7];
                span = e.target.parentNode.parentNode.childNodes[5].childNodes[1].childNodes[1];

                // console.log(e.target.parentNode.parentNode.childNodes[7]);
                ajaxComentario(idPub,idActual,txt,cantMsjs,cajonMsjs,span);
                formComentar[i].childNodes[1].value = "";
            });
        }
       

        // Publicacion flotante: Expande publicacion: Ventana de "Ver comentarios"
        //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        const tagA = $(".publicacion .interaccionPublicacion .verComentarios");
        const cuadro = $("#cuadro");
        for(let i = 0; i < tagA.length; i++){
            tagA[i].addEventListener("click",(e)=>{

                $.ajax({
                    method: "POST",
                    url: "funciones/modelo-publicacion.php",
                    data: {
                            perfil: "publicacionExplorar"
                        },
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function(o){
                        // console.log(o);

                        // console.log(e.target.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.childNodes[1].innerText);
                        var idPub = e.target.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.childNodes[1].innerText;
                        for(let i = 0; i < o.publicaciones.length; i++){
                            if(o.publicaciones[i].id_publicacion == idPub){
                                arrayComentarios = [];
                                for(let u = 0; u < o.comentarios.length; u++){
                                    if(o.comentarios[u].publicacion_id == o.publicaciones[i].id_publicacion){
                                        arrayComentarios.push(o.comentarios[u]);
                                    }
                                }
                                arrayMG = [];
                                for(let a = 0; a < o.megustas.length; a++){
                                    if(o.megustas[a].publicacion_id == o.publicaciones[i].id_publicacion){
                                        arrayMG.push(o.megustas[a]);
                                    }
                                }
                                mostrarPub(o.publicaciones[i],arrayComentarios,arrayMG);
                            }
                        }
                        cuadro.html(divPub);
                        $("#espacio").css({"display":"flex"});
                        
                    }
                })
                .then(function(){

                    //Boton heart de publicacion flotante
                    var btnHeartSolo = $("div.botonesInteraccion:nth-child(2) > button:nth-child(1)");
                    btnHeartSolo[0].addEventListener("click",(e)=>{
                        // console.log(e.target.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.childNodes[5].childNodes[1].childNodes[1]);
                        idPub = e.target.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.childNodes[1].innerText;
                        boton = e.target.parentNode;
                        span = e.target.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.childNodes[5].childNodes[1].childNodes[1];
                        ajaxMG(idPub,idActual,boton,span,1);
                    })

                    // Insertar comentario
                    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
                    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

                    //Desactivar boton con texarea sin value
                    const botonComentarSolo = $("div.inputPublicacion:nth-child(5) > form:nth-child(1) > button:nth-child(2)");
                    const textComentarSolo = $("div.inputPublicacion:nth-child(5) > form:nth-child(1) > textarea:nth-child(1)");
                    botonComentarSolo[0].disabled = true;
                    textComentarSolo[0].oninput = function(){
                        if(textComentarSolo[0].value == ""){
                            botonComentarSolo[0].disabled = true;
                        }else{
                            botonComentarSolo[0].disabled = false;
                        }
                    }; 
                    
                    const formComentarSolo = $("div.inputPublicacion:nth-child(5) > form:nth-child(1)");
                    formComentarSolo[0].addEventListener("submit",(e)=>{
                        e.preventDefault();
                        idPub = e.target.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.childNodes[1].innerText;
                        txt = e.target.childNodes[1].value;
                        cantMsjs = e.target.parentNode.parentNode.childNodes[1].childNodes.length;
                        cajonMsjs = e.target.parentNode.parentNode.childNodes[1];
                        span = "";

                        // console.log(e.target.parentNode.parentNode.childNodes[1].childNodes.length);
                        ajaxComentario(idPub,idActual,txt,cantMsjs,cajonMsjs,span,flotando = 1);
                        formComentarSolo[0].childNodes[1].value = "";
                    });
                    
                });
            })
        }
        //Cerrar publicacion flotante al dar click afuera
        espacio.addEventListener("click",(e)=>{
            // console.log(e.target.id);
            if(e.target.id == "espacio"){
                $("#espacio").css({"display":"none"});
                // location.reload();
            }
            
        });
            
    });
```

Parte de codigo php:

```
 if(isset($_POST["perfil"])){

        if($_POST["perfil"] == "cargarPublicaciones"){
        
            $id = $_POST["id"];
            try {
                include "conexion.php";
                $sql = "SELECT * FROM publicaciones WHERE perfil_id = $id ORDER BY tiempo_publicacion DESC";
                $resultado = $conn->query($sql);
            } catch (Exception $e) {
                $error = $e->getMessage();
                echo $error;
            }
            $o = 0;
            $publicaciones = array();
            while($publicacion = $resultado->fetch_assoc()){
                $publicaciones[$o] = $publicacion;
                $o++;
            }
            $sqlComentarios = "SELECT * FROM comentarios";
                $resultadoCo = $conn->query($sqlComentarios);
                $a = 0;
            $respuestaCo = array();
            while($comentario = $resultadoCo->fetch_assoc()){
                $respuestaCo[$a] = $comentario;
                $a++;
            }
            $sqlMG = "SELECT * FROM megustas";
                $resultadoMG = $conn->query($sqlMG);
                $u = 0;
            $respuestaMg = array();
            while($mg = $resultadoMG->fetch_assoc()){
                $respuestaMg[$u] = $mg;
                $u++;
            }
            $respuesta = array(
                "publicaciones"=>$publicaciones,
                "comentarios"=>$respuestaCo,
                "megustas"=>$respuestaMg
            );
            die(json_encode($respuesta));

        }

        if($_POST["perfil"] == "cargarPublicacionesExplorar"){
        
            try {
                include "conexion.php";
                $sql = "SELECT * FROM publicaciones ORDER BY tiempo_publicacion DESC";
                $resultado = $conn->query($sql);
            } catch (Exception $e) {
                $error = $e->getMessage();
                echo $error;
            }
            $o = 0;
            $publicaciones = array();
            while($perfil = $resultado->fetch_assoc()){
                $publicaciones[$o] = $perfil;
                $o++;
            }
            $sqlComentarios = "SELECT * FROM comentarios";
            $resultadoCo = $conn->query($sqlComentarios);
            $a = 0;
            $comentarios = array();
            while($comentario = $resultadoCo->fetch_assoc()){
                $comentarios[$a] = $comentario;
                $a++;
            }
            $sqlMG = "SELECT * FROM megustas";
            $resultadoMG = $conn->query($sqlMG);
            $i = 0;
            $megustas = array();
            while($megusta = $resultadoMG->fetch_assoc()){
                $megustas[$i] = $megusta;
                $i++;
            }
            $respuesta = array(
                "publicaciones"=>$publicaciones,
                "megustas"=>$megustas,
                "comentarios"=>$comentarios
            );
            die(json_encode($respuesta));

        }

        if($_POST["perfil"] == "publicacionExplorar"){
            try {
                include "conexion.php";
                $sql = "SELECT * FROM publicaciones,perfiles WHERE id_perfil = perfil_id ORDER BY tiempo_publicacion DESC";
                $resultado = $conn->query($sql);
            } catch (Exception $e) {
                $error = $e->getMessage();
                echo $error;
            }
            $o = 0;
            $infoPublicaciones = array();
            while($perfil = $resultado->fetch_assoc()){
                $infoPublicaciones[$o] = $perfil;
                $o++;
            }            
            $sqlComentarios = "SELECT * FROM comentarios, perfiles WHERE id_perfil = perfil_id";
            $resultadoComentarios = $conn->query($sqlComentarios);
            $i = 0;
            $comentarios = array();
            while($comentario = $resultadoComentarios->fetch_assoc()){
                $comentarios[$i] = $comentario;
                $i++;
            }
            $sqlMG = "SELECT * FROM megustas, perfiles WHERE id_perfil = perfil_id";
            $resultadoMG = $conn->query($sqlMG);
            $i = 0;
            $megustas = array();
            while($megusta = $resultadoMG->fetch_assoc()){
                $megustas[$i] = $megusta;
                $i++;
            }
            $publicaciones = array(
                "publicaciones"=>$infoPublicaciones,
                "comentarios"=>$comentarios,
                "megustas"=>$megustas
            );

            $conn->close();
            die(json_encode($publicaciones));

        }



        if($_POST["perfil"] == "cargarPublicacionesIndex"){
            $idActual = $_POST["id"];
            try {
                include "conexion.php";
                $sql = "SELECT * FROM publicaciones,perfiles WHERE id_perfil = perfil_id ORDER BY tiempo_publicacion DESC";
                $resultado = $conn->query($sql);
            } catch (Exception $e) {
                $error = $e->getMessage();
                echo $error;
            }
            $o = 0;
            $publicaciones = array();
            while($perfil = $resultado->fetch_assoc()){
                $publicaciones[$o] = $perfil;
                $o++;
            }

            $sqlSeguidos = "SELECT usuario_seguido FROM seguidos WHERE perfil_id = '$idActual'";
            $resultadoSeguidos = $conn->query($sqlSeguidos);
            $a = 0;
            $usuarios = array();
            while($usuario = $resultadoSeguidos->fetch_assoc()){
                $usuarios[$a] = $usuario;
                $a++;
            }

            $sqlComentarios = "SELECT * FROM comentarios, perfiles WHERE id_perfil = perfil_id";
            $resultadoComentarios = $conn->query($sqlComentarios);
            $i = 0;
            $comentarios = array();
            while($comentario = $resultadoComentarios->fetch_assoc()){
                $comentarios[$i] = $comentario;
                $i++;
            }

            $sqlMG = "SELECT * FROM megustas, perfiles WHERE id_perfil = perfil_id";
            $resultadoMG = $conn->query($sqlMG);
            $i = 0;
            $megustas = array();
            while($megusta = $resultadoMG->fetch_assoc()){
                $megustas[$i] = $megusta;
                $i++;
            }

            
            $respuesta = array(
                "Publicaciones"=>$publicaciones,
                "comentarios"=>$comentarios,
                "megustas"=>$megustas,
                "UsuariosSeguidos"=>$usuarios
            );
            // $cont = 0;
            // while($row=mysql_fetch_array($stmt)){
            //     $respuesta[$cont] = $row;
            //     $cont++;
            // }
            $conn->close();
            die(json_encode($respuesta));

        }

        if($_POST["perfil"] == "cargarPerfiles"){

            $idActual = $_POST["id"];
            include "conexion.php";
            try{
                $sql = "SELECT * FROM perfiles ORDER BY usuario_perfil DESC";
                $resultado = $conn->query($sql);
            }catch(Exception $e){
                echo "Error: ".$e->getMessage();
            }
            $a = 0;
            $perfiles = array();
            while($perfil = $resultado->fetch_assoc()){
                $perfiles[$a] = $perfil;
                $a++;
            }
           
            $sqlSeguidos = "SELECT usuario_seguido FROM seguidos WHERE perfil_id = '$idActual'";
            $resultadoSeguidos = $conn->query($sqlSeguidos);
            $a = 0;
            $usuarios = array();
            while($usuario = $resultadoSeguidos->fetch_assoc()){
                $usuarios[$a] = $usuario;
                $a++;
            }

            $respuesta = array(
                "perfiles"=>$perfiles,
                "usuarios"=>$usuarios
            );



            $conn->close();
            die(json_encode($respuesta));
        }

        if($_POST["perfil"] == "cargarMG"){
        
          // $respuesta = array(
            //     "Post"=>$_POST
            // );
            // die(json_encode($respuesta));
            // die(json_encode($_POST));

            $idLogin = $_POST["idLog"];
            $idPublicacion = $_POST["idPub"];
            try{
                include "conexion.php";
                $sql = $conn->query("SELECT perfil_id FROM megustas WHERE perfil_id = '$idLogin' AND publicacion_id = '$idPublicacion'");           
            }catch(Exception $e){
                echo "Error: ".$e->getMessage();
            }
            $megusta = array();
            while($mg=$sql->fetch_array()){
                array_push($megusta,$mg["perfil_id"]);
            }
            $busqueda = array_search($idLogin, $megusta);
            if($busqueda === false){
                $sql = $conn->query("INSERT INTO megustas(perfil_id, publicacion_id) VALUES('$idLogin','$idPublicacion')");
                $respuesta = array(
                    "megusta"=>true
                ); 
            }else{
                $sql = $conn->query("DELETE FROM megustas WHERE perfil_id = '$idLogin' AND publicacion_id = '$idPublicacion'");
                $respuesta = array(
                    "megusta"=>false
                ); 
            }
            $sql2 = $conn->query("SELECT perfil_id FROM megustas WHERE publicacion_id = '$idPublicacion'");
            $cantMGS = array();
            $i=0;
            while($cantMG=$sql2->fetch_array()){
                $cantMGS[$i] = $cantMG["perfil_id"];
                $i++;
            }
            $arrayRespuesta = array(
                "respuesta"=>$respuesta,
                "cantidad"=>$cantMGS
            );
            $conn->close();
            die(json_encode($arrayRespuesta));

        }

        if($_POST["perfil"] == "cargarComentario"){
        
            // $respuesta = array(
            //     "Post"=>$_POST
            // );
            // die(json_encode($respuesta));
            // die(json_encode($_POST));
  
            $idLogin = $_POST["idLog"];
            $idPublicacion = $_POST["idPub"];
            $txtPublicacion = $_POST["texto"];
            if($txtPublicacion !== ""){
                try{
                    include "conexion.php";
                    $stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO comentarios(perfil_id,text_comentario,publicacion_id) VALUES(?,?,?)");
                    $stmt->bind_param("isi", $idLogin, $txtPublicacion, $idPublicacion);
                    $stmt->execute();
                }catch(Exception $e){
                    echo "Error: ".$e->getMessage();
                }
                $sql2 = $conn->query("SELECT perfil_id FROM comentarios WHERE publicacion_id = '$idPublicacion'");
                $cantComentarios = array();
                $i=0;
                while($cantCo=$sql2->fetch_array()){
                    $cantComentarios[$i] = $cantCo["perfil_id"];
                    $i++;
                }
                $sql3 = $conn->query("SELECT usuario_perfil FROM perfiles WHERE id_perfil = '$idLogin'");
                $extraido= mysqli_fetch_array($sql3);
                $respuesta = array(
                    "respuesta"=>"correcto",
                    "cantidad"=>$cantComentarios,
                    "usuario"=>$extraido["usuario_perfil"]
                );
                die(json_encode($respuesta));
            }
  
          }
        
    }
```

Comment: ¿Podrías compartir algo de código y las URLs de tu frontal web y la del extremo que aloja los recursos que tratas de descargar con XHR (ajax)?

Comment: @OscarGarcia agregado, los archivos de php con las consultas se encuentran en la carpeta funciones. Disculpa si no comprendi lo solicitado.

Comment: ¿Todo está cargando bajo la misma web? ¿Podrías compartir el código PHP? Me he creado una cuenta gratuita para pegar ese servicio y he notado que de vez en cuando no carga tu página, si no un HTML que genera una cookie llamada `__test`. Es posible que, si no entregas las cabeceras adecuadas, en WAF genere algo que no es el resultado de la ejecución del PHP como se espera.

Comment: @oscargarcia Si, todo esta cargado en la misma web, es una mala practica? Te dejo una parte del php porque es mucho.

Comment: No, no es porque sea buena o mala práctica, si no por saber si necesitas enviar esas cabeceras o no (si entran en juego las políticas de CORS o no). Pero parece que aquí lo que entra en juego es [CORB](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/refs/heads/main/services/network/cross_origin_read_blocking_explainer.md). Es muy tarde, mañana echo un vistazo al código Javascript y PHP. Mientras tanto otros compañeros pueden ayudar también.

Comment: Por cierto, a primera vista parece que estás accediendo a un recurso que no existe, te redirige a una página que nuestra un error 404 y, por ese motivo, te bloquea el contenido. ¿Puedes consultar la consola de depuración, en la pestaña de Red, para ver qué URLs intentas cargar y te refieren a ese error 404? Comprueba que existan los PHP y las rutas relativas estén bien.

Comment: @OscarGarcia Verifique todos los archivos, estan todos. Quiero comentar algo, a segundos de subirlo estaba muy pesado, pesadisimo y no cargaba ninguna imagen. Despues de un tiempo por lo menos cargo la foto de perfil en la barra superior. Agregue recien los certificados ssl por si las dudas. Depurando algunos archivos no abrian el codigo "unable" pero ahora si andan bien. No se :(